# Issue with API PHP reading JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

There seems to be an issue with the API handling JSON input.
This is my API (Delete function)

```
function doDeleteCustomer() {
global $db;
if(isParamSet(array('id'))) {
    if(isParamAvailable(array('id'))) {
        $customerId = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE ID=:customerid";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(
            array(
                ':customerid' => $customerId
            )
        );
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $response = array();
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["status"] = 200;
            $response["data"] = array();
            $response["message"] = "Successfully removed customer!";
        } else {
            $response = array();
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["status"] = 400;
            $response["data"] = array();
            $response["message"] = "Unable to remove customer!";
        }
        return json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

}

When I test it in Postman everything works fine, but I have provide the information in x-www-form-urlencoded.

[image]

But when I want to give the input by raw JSON data I get a message that the required id field is missing...What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: So which code is doing that check. Not the code you show us

Comment: @RiggsFolly. I hope I don't say anything stupid as I'm a complete noobie on API. But do you mean the client.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `json_decode` before processing your data if you intend to make your application accept json. Alternatively, if you'd like it to support both, you could use `try catch` in order to switch.

More information about json_decode can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I'm a noobie and still very much learning API. Where do I need to put the json_decode?

Comment: I haven't touched PHP in a long time, but... From what I understand, `$_REQUEST` is the variable that will receive the body of the request...

Therefore, if it is receiving JSON it will be something like this `$_REQUEST = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';`

If you notice, the variable will equate to a string... so you need to use json_decode in order to turn it into an object/dictionary/hashmap (whatever you call it) in order to process it... so I believe you need to put `json_decode($_REQUEST)` before the if statement, then check whether `id` is present in the request body message

Answer (score 0):

I have found it, thanks to the this from Zirc.

All I needed to do was `$_REQUEST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`
before the first if statement